# VBA: object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, object

I wrote a very simple macro, that opens another workbook and select range of data from this workbook.
However, I keep receiving this warning: object doesn't support this property or method

What is wrong?

```
Sub data()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim filename As String
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim lastcolumn As Integer
Dim range_to_copy As Range

'open workbook
filename = "C:\Users\mk\Desktop\sales report\Sales Report.xls"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename)
Set ws = wb.Sheets("data")

lastcolumn = wb.ws.Cells(1, wb.ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastrow = wb.ws.Cells(wb.ws.Roows.Count, 1).End(xlToLeft).Row

range_to_copy = Range("Cells(1,1):Cells(lastrow,lastcolumn)")

End sub
```

Answer (score 2):

A number of things wrong.

**Edit:**
`Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim lastcolumn As Integer`
An `Integer` can store numbers up to 32,767.  This won't be a problem for columns, but will throw an overflow error on the row number.  It's better to use the `Long` data type - numbers up to 2,147,486,647.

The `ws` variable already references the workbook so you just need:
`lastcolumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

`lastrow = wb.ws.Cells(wb.ws.Roows.Count, 1).End(xlToLeft).Row`
`Rows` only has one `o` in it.
**Edit:** `xlToLeft` looks at the right most cell and works to the left.  As you're looking for rows you need to use `xlUp` which looks at the last cell and works up.

`range_to_copy = Range("Cells(1,1):Cells(lastrow,lastcolumn)")`
This is an object so you must `Set` it.  The cells references are separated by a comma and should not be held as a string.

```
Sub data()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim filename As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastcolumn As Long
    Dim range_to_copy As Range

    'open workbook
    filename = "C:\Users\mk\Desktop\sales report\Sales Report.xls"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("data")

    lastcolumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set range_to_copy = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))

End Sub
```

Note:  Every range reference is preceded by the worksheet reference.  Without this it will always look at the currently active sheet so if you aren't on the `data` sheet the following will fail as the second cell reference will look at the activesheet.
`ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))`

It might be worth checking out the `With....End With` code block.

Comment: `lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlToLeft).Row` will always either return 1048576 or 65536, depending on Excel file format.  Early morning for you too? (Or is it late night?)   ;-)

Comment: @YowE3K.  lol, was thinking who the hell put `xlToLeft` in there that'll never work.... early morning for me.  Couple of hours earlier than @Shaido so I've got a better excuse. :)  That reminded me of another error that I forgot to mention to OP - `Dim lastrow As Integer`.  I'll update my answer.  Cheers.

Comment: I was a bit upset when I saw you picking up the errors in Shai's answer - I wanted to do it - so I was glad when I noticed that you had overlooked something! :D

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code.
Try

```
lastcolumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set range_to_copy = Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastcolumn))
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain why should I use ws.Cells insetad of wb.ws.Cells?

Comment: `wb`is a workbook-object. It has a property `sheets` which is an array of all sheets within the workbook. You already accessing this property to assign the worksheet you want to work with to the variable `ws`. From there on, you can (and should) use `ws`. `wb` has no property `ws`, so this cannot work. You could use `wb.sheets("data").Cells`, but why would you do this if you have already `ws` as variable.

Answer (score 0):

Once you defined and set your `ws` worksheet object, you don't need to refer to the `wb` object anymore, since your `ws` worksheet object is fully quallified with `Sheets("data")` in `wb` workbook.

Now, all you need to do is use the `With` statement, like in the code below:

```
Set ws = wb.Sheets("data")    
With ws
    lastcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set range_to_copy = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))
End With
```

Comment: Still early morning?  You forgot to `Set`  your range. :D

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook LOL ;) , yep